# ER Chen Business Rules

Tags: database, entity

With this [ER Diagram](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/1brvb.png) what three business rules can be assumed?

I know it's simple but I've searched for an answer to this question but I have yet to find anything that explicitly states what I am looking for in terms of exactly how to pronounce each rule.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each student may study more than one module.
2. Each module may have more than one student studying it.
3. Each module may have one or more prerequisite modules that must be studied by the student before studying this module.

Comment: Why are both rules 1 and 2 may? wouldn't one of these be a must because of the solid line?

Comment: I suspect that dotted lines imply an optional relationship, in which case a given module could have from zero to many prerequisites. Otherwise, how would a student ever get started?

Comment: @RedFilter Half of the Student to Module line is dotted, the side of the Module is solid?

Comment: @RedFilter A student must have one or more modules. A module may have one or more students?